# Deploying custom master page in a custom web template across web applications

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

We have custom master page and we also created a custom web template which is used by site collections and sub sites.

If we need to update master page we currently have to do following steps,

- Update master page which is in a SharePoint module project, deploying it to server changes nothing but I still do it
- Update master page manually by going to site(collection) settings
- Create a new web template and download it as a wsp
- Redeploy this new web template

Is there any better way of doing this ?

What I would like to do is to deploy master page to SharePoint maybe using VS and then all site collection which are already using this custom master page show the changes without any further changes.

Comment: if the master page is not customized, updating it in the hive through wsp update should be enough to reflect the changes in all sites. or am I missing something?

Comment: @TiagoDuarte do you put master page in hive ? I believe it lives within custom web template. You can save a template then download it and you will see custom master page in it